# LayoutAnimation expanding all lists on click of a button - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a component in which I'm rendering lists based on data from a database. For the list to work, I'm using `Object.entries` and pushed all the lists to the array. And later rendering the array inside the return method.

Inside the list, I have a view and a button. The view is hidden by default. I'm using `LayoutAnimation` to expand the list to display the view onClick of the button. But when I click the button all the views are getting displayed.

Is there any better way to collapse and display the view related to the particular list. I only want to display the view which I'm clicking the button.

Function to collapse and display the view,

```
changeLayout = () => {
        LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);
        this.setState({ expanded: !this.state.expanded });
    }
```

And in render method I'm pushing the lists to an array,

```
var lists = [];
Object.entries(this.state.values).forEach(([key, val]) =>
            lists.push(
                <View>
                    <List key={val["val1"]} style={styles.list}>
                        <ListItem>
                            <Body style={{ paddingLeft: 50, paddingRight: 50 }}>
                                <Text>{val["name"]}</Text>
                            </Body>
                            <Right>
                                <TouchableOpacity 
                                    style={styles.button}
                                    onPress = {this.changeLayout}
                                >
                                    <Text style={styles.btnText}>Status</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                            </Right>
                        </ListItem>
                        <View style={{ height: this.state.expanded ? null : 0, overflow: 'hidden' }}>
                        <Text style={styles.text}>
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                            Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's 
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                    </List>
                </View>
            )
```

And in the return method I'm calling the array as

```
<Content>
   {lists}
</Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach.

> ListItem.js

```
state = {
      expanded: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental &&
      UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
    LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.row}
          onPress={() => this.toggleExpand()}>
          <Text style={[styles.title, styles.font]}>{this.props.title}</Text>
          <Icon
            name={
              this.state.expanded ? 'keyboard-arrow-up' : 'keyboard-arrow-down'
            }
            size={30}
            color="#000"
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.parentHr} />
        {this.state.expanded && (
          <View style={styles.child}>
            <Text style={styles.detailStyle}>{this.props.data}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }

  toggleExpand = () => {
    this.setState({expanded: !this.state.expanded});
  };
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  title: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: '#000',
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    height: 56,
    paddingLeft: 25,
    paddingRight: 18,
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderWidth: 0.1,
    borderColor: '#94979c',
  },
  parentHr: {
    height: 1,
    color: '#f8f8f8',
    width: '100%',
  },
  child: {
    backgroundColor: '#f8f8f8',
    padding: 16,
  },
  detailStyle: {
    textAlign: 'justify',
  },
});
```

> App.js

```
renderListItem = () => {
    const items = [];
    for (item of this.state.values) {
      items.push(
        <ListItem title={item.title} data={item.description} key={item.id} />,
      );
    }
    return items;
  };
```

> Return Method

```
<ScrollView>{this.renderListItem()}</ScrollView>
```

Let me know if this helps

Comment: No. It's not working. I have a array in which lists are rendering. I would like to display only the view relative to the specific list. Is there something to set an ID or something?

Comment: Share me an example of your data and the state you are storing it. So I will have a clear idea. Mine is an example. I will edit the answer accordingly

Comment: Please refer to the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-wing-g1hqm?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Bro where is Database.js from which you have imported firebase. Your shared code does not show the project properly

Comment: Database.js is the database config files. It's simply an object to connect to the database. I have imported the function from the page.